# Ability to ensure message was successfully sent to Event Hub from APIM

Tags: azure-eventhub

Is it possible to ensure that a message was successfully delivered to an Event Hub when sending it with the log-to-eventhub policy in API Management?

Edit: In our solution we cannot allow any request to proceed if a message was not delivered to the Event Hub. As far as I can tell the log-to-eventhub policy doesn't check for this.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoveflow!

**Note:** Once the data has been passed to an Event Hub, it is persisted and will wait for Event Hub consumers to process it. The Event Hub does not care how it is processed; it just cares about **making sure the message will be successfully delivered**.

For more details, refer “[Why send to an Azure Event Hub?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-log-to-eventhub-sample#why-send-to-an-azure-event-hub)”.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Let me clarify my question, what I'm looking for is a way to make sure a message was successfully sent to the Event Hub. If it fails when using the .NET you get an exception, if you however use the log-to-eventhub policy in Azure API Management there doesn't seem to be a way to know if the message was successfully delivered.

Answer (score 0):

Event Hubs is built on top of Service Bus.  According to the Service Bus [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-transfers-locks-settlement#settling-send-operations),

> Using any of the supported Service Bus API clients, send operations into Service Bus are always explicitly settled, meaning that the API operation waits for an acceptance result from Service Bus to arrive, and then completes the send operation.
>
> If the message is rejected by Service Bus, the rejection contains an error indicator and text with a "tracking-id" inside of it. The rejection also includes information about whether the operation can be retried with any expectation of success. In the client, this information is turned into an exception and raised to the caller of the send operation. If the message has been accepted, the operation silently completes.
>
> When using the AMQP protocol, which is the exclusive protocol for the .NET Standard client and the Java client and which is an option for the .NET Framework client, message transfers and settlements are pipelined and completely asynchronous, and it is recommended that you use the asynchronous programming model API variants.
>
> A sender can put several messages on the wire in rapid succession without having to wait for each message to be acknowledged, as would otherwise be the case with the SBMP protocol or with HTTP 1.1. Those asynchronous send operations complete as the respective messages are accepted and stored, on partitioned entities or when send operation to different entities overlap. The completions might also occur out of the original send order.

I think this means the SDK is getting a receipt for each message.

This theory is further aided by the [RetryPolicy Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.retrypolicy?view=azure-dotnet) used in the [ClientEntity.RetryPolicy Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.cliententity.retrypolicy?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_ClientEntity_RetryPolicy) of the [EventHubSender Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubsender?view=azure-dotnet).

In the [API Management section on logging-to-eventhub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#log-to-eventhub), there is also a section on retry intervals.  Below that are sections on modifying the return response or taking action on certain status codes.
Once the status codes of a failed logging attempt are known, you can modify the policies to take action on failed logging attempts.

Comment: Could you provide an example? I tried putting the log-to-eventhub policy in a retry, using 10060 as condition. Are you sure that the retry policy and return response are part of the log-to-eventhub policy? To me they look like different policies.

This is the output from the log-to-eventhub policy:
log-to-eventhub (0.425 ms)
{
    "message": "Log to EventHub Policy was successfully processed"
}

As you see, the policy didn't report any problems, even though I've denied the subnet APIM is in to access the Event Hub.